# Can you run CAU on an Exchange 2010 DAG cluster?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-server-2012-r2, failovercluster, dag, cluster-aware-updating

I've searched for this and I expected it to be a common topic, but I can't find any information on it. Given that the Exchange DAG is built on top of WCF, will CAU properly handle updating a DAG cluster? Specifically, will the Exchange servers be placed into DAG maintenance mode prior to updates running or the server being restarted? Or is CAU agnostic to the DAG.

If it doesn't do this automatically, would it make sense to hack in DAG support using the PreUpdateScript and PostUpdateScript params?

Does anyone do this? Right now we handle software updates on our 5 machine DAG is a very manual way. Scripting it is a possibility, but building ontop of, or using CAU, seems like a better approach. Any suggestions?